# Retornar void em um método ActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho esté método abaixo, e preciso ter uma condição que dependendo ele vai abrir uma nova aba com uma url:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //condição
    return Response.Write(@"<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>window.open('page.html','_blank').focus();</script>");
}
```

tentei

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), sb.ToString(), true);
```

Mas ele sempre retorna que não é possível retornar `void` em um método `ActionResult`. E eu preciso mesmo que abra em nova aba.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113388/discussion-on-question-by-mariana-retornar-void-em-um-metodo-actionresult) - quem quiser ler ou prosseguir, basta clicar no link

Answer (score 3):

`ActionResult` é para usar com métodos para isso, se não vai usar um `ActionResult` então não tem porque forçar usar

O `Response.Write` não faz parte do namespace  `System.Web.Mvc`, no retorno de um ActionResult deve conter:

- `System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult`
- `System.Web.Mvc.EmptyResult`
- `System.Web.Mvc.FileResult`
- `System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult`
- `System.Web.Mvc.JavaScriptResult`
- `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult`
- `System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult`
- `System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult`
- `System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase`

Então se é pra usar uma "string" como saída use o ContentResult:

```
public ContentResult Index()  
{  
    return Content(@"<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>window.open('page.html','_blank').focus();</script>"));  
}
```

Que por padrão vai retornar como `text/html`

Comment: Eu preciso do ActionResult, porque eu tenho um case, onde depenendo eu abro um RedirectToAction, neste específico, que eu preciso abrir em uma nova aba a `url`

Comment: @Mariana ContentResult é DERIVADO de ActionResult, logo deve funcionar. ... abrir em NOVA ABA é responsabilidade do JavaScript depois dá página baixada, não ocorre no BackEnd

Comment: Quando eu mudo para contentResult, ele me retorna: Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult" em "System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult"

Comment: Quando uso o Content, ele abre, porém a página que eu estava, ela perde as informações.

Comment: Mas esse redirecttoroueresult é outra coisa e provavelmente outra rota, sem olhar o que vc fez não dá pra entender, provavelmente suas rotas foram configuradas como redirecionamento o q não tem sentido, pq o resultado é disparado pelo front

Comment: o que ela pretende fazer esse código não é o suficiente Guilmerme ela precisa passar uma flag para view e nessa view abrir a página.

Answer (score -3):

talvez algo nesse sentido:

```
public ActionResult NewWindow()
{
    return Content("<script>window.open('{url}','_blank')</script>");
}
```

Comment: Ele abra em nova aba, mas não abre o link correto, faz assim http://localhost:2021/%7Bhttps//url, e a página atual, perde os dados